# PHP with comet/ajax and ob_flush

Tags: javascript, php, typo3, comet

I'm trying to use `ob_flush()` and `flush()` from a TYPO3 controller, but the result is weird. In the web-browser console I can see that each flush does not lead to one response in Javascript; there's no one-to-one correspondence between a flush on the server and a reaction in javascript. This is the code:

```
// PHP
foreach ($ids as $id) {
  echo $id;
  ob_flush(); // <-- Flush 1, 2, 3, ...
  flush();
  // more data processing...
}

// Javascript
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200) {
  }
  else if (xhr.readyState > 2) {
    console.log(xhr.responseText); // <-- Can log "123" in one go
  }
}
```

How do I force one `flush` to lead to exactly one response in Javascript?

Could it be that the flush occurs so often that Apache2 don't have time to react?

**Edit**: Solved by including this after `echo`:

```
echo str_pad('',4096)."\n";
```

Comment: That's not the right way to solve the problem. Some other output filter in Apache is buffering the result - probably mod_deflate - see http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_deflate.html#deflatebuffersize

Comment: @symcbean I've already tried to disable `mod_deflate` using `apache_setenv('no-gzip', '1')`, without success.